# Eventos de CheckBox dinamicos C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms, eventos, checkbox

Como puedo hacer eventos en un conjunto de checkBox que estoy creando, es decir tengo mi código:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < NcheckBox; i++)
    {
     CheckBox cbxN = new CheckBox();
     cbxN.Text = nameCheckbox[i];
     cbxN.AutoPostBack = true;
     cbxN.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cbxN_CheckedChanged);
     divcbxCompatibilidad.Controls.Add(cbxN);
    } 


 protected void cbxN_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
    <div id="divcbxCompatibilidad" runat="server" class="divcbx"></div>
```

y requiero disparar el evento `cbxN_CheckedChanged` cuando algún `CheckBox` es seleccionado pero solo consigo que se refresque la pagina desde el `page_Load`.

Comment: en la pregunta has puesto el tag asp.net y el windows-forms, no entiendo, que tipo de desarrollo estas realizando?

Comment: Has visto que te subscibes a un evento diferente al que declaras? Cuando tienes que subscribirte al evento no le pases parámetros, no lo pongas con paréntesis, sólo el nombre del método. Con eso se te debería ejecutar.

Answer (score -1):

Si los eventos no se disparan, es probable que sea por una de dos razones:

- Los controles se recrean demasiado tarde en el ciclo de vida de la página. Intenta crear los controles durante OnInit.
- La validación está impidiendo la devolución. Para solucionar esto, puedes establecer CausesValidation en falso en todos los controles CheckBox.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya puedo invocar al evento pero por lo que veo al dar click en el checkbox va primero al page_Load y luego al evento

Comment: lo hago de esta forma
 cbxfilt1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cbxfilt1_CheckedChanged); 
  cbxfilt1.Init += cbxfilt1_CheckedChanged; 
  De cualquiera de las dos formas funciona pero siempre va primero al page_Load

Comment: Recuerda que en ASP.Net, cada vez que se provoca un postback de cualquier tipo, incluido el manejo de eventos como hacer clic en los botones o un checkbox, se está trabajando con una nueva instancia de su clase de la  página, que debe reconstruirse desde cero. Cualquier trabajo que hayas hecho anteriormente para construir la página en el servidor se ha ido. Eso significa ejecutar todo el ciclo de vida de la página, incluido el código de carga de la página (Pate_Load) y no solo el código de clic.